# Converting an Eclipse project to Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, intellij-idea

I have an Eclipse project that uses many third party libs (jars). I want to convert it into a Maven project so that I can build and deploy it using the command line on a remote machine. Is there a recommended way/tool of converting the this project to maven (or any other command line based build system)? I also have an IntelliJ IDEA that I can use if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue, wherein we manually deployed jars into local maven repository by the help of command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

1) -Dfile is the jar you want to convert

2) -DgroupId will be the generated groupid for this jar same as artifact and version.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select your project
2. right click select `Configure`
3. select `Convert to maven project`.

If no dependency management tool is used then you have to add the dependencies manually in pom.xml. It will hardly take 10 -20 minutes by looking at the lib folder in your old project.
Also you might need to change the folder structure of newly created project ([see here the standard structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)).

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse/STS IDE's right on that project you can find configure-->select from the menu which u want to convert...........